# Store an array in PHP between page calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Suppose I have a page called view.php, if I give an argument like view.php?q=fruit, it creates a list of fruits stored in an array. I want change the content of a label in a page to be changed to the content of that array if a slider in that page changes. In the example above, this array contains: `$list = array('banana', 'apple', 'orange');` I want to have a slider in the page and a lable that when the user changes the slider's value, the label's text changes to 'banana', 'apple', ...
I heard aboue sessions in PHP but since there may be lots of calls to this page in multiple tabs, I think this wouldn't be a good idea. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what the problem with sessions is. Could you elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: what needs to be stored between page calls? it sounds like you just need some kind of javascript solution. I don't think your pages need to reload when the slider value changes

Comment: I think sessions would be the right way to go.

Comment: session IS the right way to do !

Comment: why would he use a session? this sounds like it can be done 100% client side with javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK. I found what I wanted. I found a pretty neat slider here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

then I used in in my page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Slider - Snap to increments</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="jquery/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>


        <?php 

            $list = array('apple','orange','banana');

        ?>

        <script>
            var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($list) ?>;
            $(function() {
                $( "#slider" ).slider({
                    value:1,
                    min: 0,
                    max: arrayFromPHP.length - 1,
                    step: 1,
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#amount" ).val(arrayFromPHP[ui.value]);
                    }
                });
                $( "#amount" ).val( arrayFromPHP[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )] );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="demo">

            <p>
                <label for="amount">Current selection:</label>
                <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
            </p>

            <div id="slider"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that I used Rob's answer as my source and all the credit's go to him. But since it was not **EXACTLY** what I wanted, I decided to post my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the only difference between different tabs would be the list that's generated. So your PHP code doesn't need to account for anything except which list you're going to be using. Here's a quick jquery mockup. With some CSS, and maybe some jquery animation, your slider could work without any page reloads at all.

```
<?php 
$list = array(
   'fruit' => array('apple','orange','banana'),
   'soemthing' => array('a', 'b', 'c')
);
?>

<div id="Label">Click one of the list items to change this</div>

<ul id="Slider">
  <?php foreach ($list[$_GET['q']] as $item) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $item; ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#Slider li').click(function() {
       $("#Label").text($(this).text());
       // you can have some other logic here to decide what to do when the slider is changed
   });
</script>
```

Comment: OK. I tested this but theres a slight problem here. I want to access that array's elements in the jQuery script (the commented area). You've printed the arrray's elements and you access them via those items. How can I access that array in the commented area?

Comment: I want something like this: In the first load of PHP, create a **ONE DIMENSIONAL** array which contains all of the necessary items. (in C#: `String[] list = getList('Fruits')`) When the slider's value is changed, change some text to the value of that array in that index. In C# I would write: `label1.Text = list[slider1.Value]`

Comment: You could use (JavaScript Code): `var list = eval('(<?php echo json_encode($list[$_GET['q']]); ?>)');`

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use a jquery solution .

store your array in your jquery code .

then call it on change function of your slider

like this ,

```
$('.slider').change(function(){


var index = $(this).index();

var label = labelsarray[index];

$('#label').data(label);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For slides I also do recommend jquery like others do, remember you can have asynch loads as well.

I don't remember the url but I had seen an amazing tutorial on jQuery with asynch load.

Some keywords: js asynch, image load jquery, jquery scroll

Try google with jquery scroll asynch it was an excellent tutorial with image loading asynchronously in many ways (by hovering, clicking, scrolling etc).